# SSIS is rounding off the decimal value when reading from the flat file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2017

I have a flat file with the below value:

```
AI9983|01|20170802|119965.57|0.000000|0.000000|||
AI9983|01|20170803|119713.62|-0.210019|-0.210019|||
```

I read the file, the value `119965.57` gets stored as `119965.60`
the value 119713.62 gets stored as `119713.60`.

When reading the flat-file the variable is set as `float[DT_R4]`
It gets stored in the database as `decimal(28,2)`.

Can someone help me to sort this out, I need to store the value as it is in the flat file into the database.

I am not using any derived column or transformation here.

Answer (score 0):

Float will not return a reliable result, so it is challenging to use in database work.

In the flat file connection manager, go to the columns tab, select the column and change the data type to numeric with a DataPrecision of 28 and Scale of 6 (Based on the sample data provided in the question).

Comment: when i do that the negative values are getting affected. It works when i change from DT_R4 to DT_R8

Comment: numeric supports negative values.  How are the negatives affected?  R8 is just a larger float value, beware of that because you won't necessarily get the same results twice.

Comment: oh I see.  Looking at your data example, you need a scale of 6 decimal places.  I'll update the response